# document.parentWindow "The specified cast is not valid"

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, automation

In C# I am writing some automation code with InternetExplorer.Application (an out of process COM server).

I have a "`dynamic browser`" variable holding a reference to this automation object and am able to access

`dynamic body = browser.document.body;`

```
browser.document.getElementById("someInput").value = "test";
```

but am completely unable to access the window object, either through

`browser.document.parentWindow` or `browser.document.defaultView`.

For example:

```
browser.document.parentWindow.execScript("alert('hello')");
```

or

```
dynamic window = browser.document.parentWindow;
```

When I try to access a window object like above (or with defaultView) I always get the exception messages "Error: Specified cast is not valid." Why is this?

There is another question similar to this here on SA, but the accepted answer was about a threading issue with what I believe was an inproc server using the WebBrowser control, and again I am using an out or process server, so I don't believe any threading issue applies to my problem.

Techincal details: Windows 7 64 bit, Internet Explorer 11, .NET 4.0 console application

Comment: Have you checked, which object `browser` actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to mark my class as a single threaded apartment with the [STAThread] attribute over the main entry point. I had thought that since it was an out of process COM server there wouldn't be any synchronization issues.